# vs 2012 Web.Config transformation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, web.config-transform

I am trying to add a set of URL Rewriting rules but only to the published version of the web site I'm developing.

I find all sorts of examples if i want to change say the connection string value, but I cannot find an example of how to add something that does ot already exists in the main web.config.

What I need is to add the rewrite node under the system.WebServer.

Comment: I'm sure someone can help, but it would be helpful to show what you want in your dev and prod configs.

Comment: What I do is link to an external config file from within my web config file, then generate that.  Then all I have to do is recycle the app pool after generating the config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to use `xdt:Transform="Insert"` attribute within a tag that you want added during transformation. Read more about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

You can take the below sample as a starting point (which is my `Web.Release.config` file):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- For more information on using Web.config transformation visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=125889 -->

<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <!-- Enable static content caching in release mode -->
    <system.webServer xdt:Transform="Insert">
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="5.00:00:00" cacheControlCustom="public" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```